# How do I create multiple subsets?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a dataset within which one of the variables recurs. I want to create subsets for all contents of the repeated variables, so that I can use them as groups rather than individual data points. For example, I have Category 1 repeated 20 times but I want to create a subset of all data for Category 1 with contents for 20 entries.
The only solution I know (I'm a noob) is to use the subset command for each of the categories.

```
Category 1 = data[Category 1== "Category1", ]
```

As Category 1 repeats every 20 entries, so there are 19 categories in total. So I am individually using the subset command 19 times. Is there some way that R can identify Category 1 and sort the contents into subsets without me having to create each one individually?

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please give a [mre] in your question! Eventually you can use `split()`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `split` function to create a list of subsets based on a column.  The list will have the "splitting" groups as names.

Using the `PlantGrowth` dataset as an example:

```
summary(PlantGrowth)
#      weight       group   
#  Min.   :3.590   ctrl:10  
#  1st Qu.:4.550   trt1:10  
#  Median :5.155   trt2:10  
#  Mean   :5.073            
#  3rd Qu.:5.530            
#  Max.   :6.310

split(PlantGrowth, PlantGrowth[["group"]])
# $ctrl
#    weight group
# 1    4.17  ctrl
# 2    5.58  ctrl
# 3    5.18  ctrl
# 4    6.11  ctrl
# 5    4.50  ctrl
# 6    4.61  ctrl
# 7    5.17  ctrl
# 8    4.53  ctrl
# 9    5.33  ctrl
# 10   5.14  ctrl
#  
# $trt1
#    weight group
# 11   4.81  trt1
# 12   4.17  trt1
# 13   4.41  trt1
# 14   3.59  trt1
# 15   5.87  trt1
# 16   3.83  trt1
# 17   6.03  trt1
# 18   4.89  trt1
# 19   4.32  trt1
# 20   4.69  trt1
#  
# $trt2
#    weight group
# 21   6.31  trt2
# 22   5.12  trt2
# 23   5.54  trt2
# 24   5.50  trt2
# 25   5.37  trt2
# 26   5.29  trt2
# 27   4.92  trt2
# 28   6.15  trt2
# 29   5.80  trt2
# 30   5.26  trt2
```

Comment: simple and concise, `base-r` rules!

Answer (score 1):

This should solve the issue you are facing. I have tried to replicate similar setting as the issue you have described.

```
set.seed(1234)
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(
      x=rnorm(25),
      y=rnorm(25),
      g=rep(factor(LETTERS[1:5]), 5)
)

tt <- df %>% group_split(g)

split_df<-function(list){
  for (i in 1:length(list)){
    assign(paste0("df",i), list[[i]], envir = .GlobalEnv)
  }
}

split_df(tt)
```

All different categories will be created as separate dataframe in your enviornment

Comment: It is not a good idea to create a bunch of objects. It is better to have them in a list. You should put `library(...)` in your code for the needed packages.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I have added library....However, the question specifically wanted as different df. Hence, I moved them to different dataframe